# SUMPRODUCT with OR criterias

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A          B               C         D        E        F         G
1               Profit           1.Sales  2.Sale   3.sale      
2   Product A     50              500       600       0      Product A   110
3   Product A     60                0       400       0      Product B   90  
4   Prodcut A     20                0         0       0      Product C   130
5   Product B     90              800         0       500
6   Product C     80                0         0       400
7   Product C     50              300       750       200
8   =""           =""             =""        =""       =""
```

In **Column A** different products are listed. *It can happen that the same products appear several times in the list.* In **Column B** you can find the budgeted profit for each product and in **Columns C:E** the different sales of each product.

In **Column G** the sum of the profit of each product is shown in case the product has any sales. For example *Product A* has no sale in **Row 4**; therefore the sum of its profit is *B2+B3 = 110*.

I use the following formula to get the sum of the profit:

```
G2 = SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$8,(($C$2:$C$8>0)+($D$2:$D$8>0)+($E$2:$E$8>0)>0)*($A$2:$A$8=F2))
```

This formula works perfectly so far.

However, now I want to change this formula to only count in the Products that have a **Sale > 500** so I modified the above formula to the following:

```
G2 = SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$8,(($C$2:$C$8>500)+($D$2:$D$8>500)+($E$2:$E$8>500)>500)*($A$2:$A$8=F2))
```

With this formula I get a value of 0 instead of 50 for Product A.

Where is my mistake in the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Formula Auditing ► Evaluate Formula` to examine what is happening at each step.

```
= SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$B$7,((($C$1:$C$7>500)+($D$1:$D$7>500)+($E$1:$E$7>500))>0)*($A$1:$A$7=F2))
```

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for your answer. It works perfectly. Can you tell me what the rule is for the >0 which comes in the end of the addition of the three formulas. If I only want to show the once that are >0 I have to put but if I only want to show >500 I delete it. Why is it like that?

Comment: @Michi The `>0` at the end in your first formula is superfluous.

Comment: When I take it out I get 160 instead of 110.

Comment: Oops.  Needs to be >0 for both!!

Comment: The only thing I do not understand is why I have to keep the >0 at the end of the first formulas when I want to select all values with >0 but when I want to select all values with >500 the >500 does not have to be in the end of the first formula.

Comment: Because TRUE = 1

Comment: @Michi See edit with corrected formula.  If still confused, use the `Formula Evaluator` tool to step through each stage.